# Assignment: determining sets are bases of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is question from an assignment I'm working on:

> Which **two** of the following three sets in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$?
>
> \begin{align*}
> B_1&=\{(1,0,1),(6,4,5),(-4,-4,7)\}\\
> B_2&=\{(2,1,3),(3,1,-3),(1,1,9)\}\\
> B_3&=\{(3,-1,2),(5,1,1),(1,1,1)\}
> \end{align*}

Thanks to software, I know that the answer is $B_1$ and $B_3$, as $B_2$ the only linearly dependent set of the three - and in this case, an LD set can't be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Manually, I've put all three sets in RREF, and all three can be reduced to

$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
{1}&{0}&{0}&{0}\\
{0}&{1}&{0}&{0}\\
{0}&{0}&{1}&{0}
\end{array}\right]
$$

This also checks out when computed by software.

Since all three sets reduce to the same RREF, how can I prove that these sets are linearly (in)dependent?

Comment: check if the matrix with the vectors as rows or columns has determinant 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $B_{2}$, this is linearly independent if the only solution to

$$a(2,1,3)^{T} + b (3,1,-3)^{T} +c(1,1,9)^{T} = 0$$
has the trivial solution $a=b=c=0$

or 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2&3&1\\
1&1&1\\
3&-3&9
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Take $-2R_{2} +R_{1}\rightarrow R_{1}$, $-3R_{2} + R_{3}\rightarrow R_{3}$ $-1/6 R_{3}\rightarrow R_{3}$

To get 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&-1\\
1&1&1\\
0&1&-1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$

So the rank is clearly less than 3 hence there are infinitely many solutions. If we continue by taking $-1R_{1} + R_{3}\rightarrow R_{3}$ and perform a row swap, we get

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1\\
0&1&-1\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$

At this point, you can either continue taking the system to RREF, note that since the system has a row of zeros and is homogeneous, it must be infinitely many solutions, or perform back-substitution beginning with $c=s$ where $s\in \mathbb{R}$.

The choice of row operations are more or less arbitrary, I mainly did them because of the $1$ in row 2 for ease of calculations. It isn't precisely Gaussian Elimination because I did not start with a row exchange so that the leading 1 is in the first pivot column, but that does not matter. As soon as we got a row of zeros, that showed that Row 3 was a linear combination of Row 1 and Row 2, hence the dimension that these three vectors spans is $2$ so it cannot span $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand why those particular EROs would be performed, could you please explain? I can find rank 3 for all three matrices by RREF-ing them and getting the matrix described in the original question.

Comment: Elementary Row Operations, or elementary operations on rows. Sorry if that was a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @user2615799 I've expanded my answer. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the expansion on your answer, but why go on this tangent in particular? You mentioned that it's arbitrary; it seems like the chances of falling upon such a configuration are tiny. This being said, why stop at this arbitrary step? How can one tell when to stop reducing?

Comment: I stopped when I got to a row of zeros by a sequence of elementary row operations because that one row of zeros implies the dimension is at most 2, hence it cannot possibly be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

They were arbitrary in the sense that this isn't the only sequence of Elementary row operations that take me to RREF, you can always follow the Gaussian Elimination algorithm and achieve the same RREF form which will have a row of zeros.

I should point out that this is equivalent to GA316's answer, but I did more brute force computation.

Comment: That explanation is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let V={$v_1,v_2,...,v_n$} be a set of n vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. then V is linearly independent iff the matrix A=($v_1,v_2,...,v_n$) is invertible where v_i is the ith column of A . proving this result is an easy exercise
.

Comment: @DevenWare sorry, I cant understand your command. say it little more clearly.

Comment: nevermind, sorry!